# use enum type from another class

Tags: c++, class, enums

I've read all the suggestions I've found in the following links

1. [c++ typedef another class's enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902095/c-typedef-another-classs-enum)
2. http://forums.devarticles.com/c-c-help-52/how-to-use-enum-when-it-is-in-another-class-17773.html
3. http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=435215
4. [How do I use the Enum value from a class in another part of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506750/how-do-i-use-the-enum-value-from-a-class-in-another-part-of-code)

but still wasn't able to find a solution to my problem:

> I need to construct an object of `class A` (whose constructor expects as an input
>   parameter an enumerative type of that class) from inside a function of an object of `class B`

Here are the code snippets:

**File A.h:**

```
Class A{
    public:
       enum FileType{TEXT, BIN};

       /*! This constructor initializes the data from a given file
        *  (binary, text, image). 
        */
       A(const std::string& filename, FileType type);

}
```

**File A.cpp:**

```
A::A(const std::string& filename, FileType type){
 ...
}
```

**File B.h:**

```
Class B{

    private:
       A objectOfClassA;

    public:
       enum FileType{TEXT = A::FileType::TEXT, BIN = A::FileType::BIN}; //<----THIS IS NOT WORKING!           
       foo_func(const std::string& filename, FileType type);

}
```

**File B.cpp:**

```
void B::foo_func(const std::string& filename, FileType type){

    this->objectOfClassA(filename, type); //should construct an object of class A
    ... //do stuff with objectOfClassA
}
```

**File main.cpp:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    B objectOfClassB;
    objectOfClassB.foo_func("file_path", foo_func.TEXT);

}
```

By trying to run main program I get this error from compiler in the **B.cpp** file at line of function `foo_func`:

> no match for call to ‘(A)
>   (std::basic_string, B::FileType&)’

which means that I'm not using the correct enum type to call `A class` constructor, but how can I fix this?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `objectOfClassB.foo_func("file_path", A::FileType::TEXT);` or `objectOfClassB.foo_func("file_path", B::FileType::TEXT);` or `objectOfClassB.foo_func("file_path", objectOfClassB.FileType::TEXT);`

Comment: Seriously, the links you posted have the answer.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes please read all the question, cause inside the ***B.h*** quote I'm saying that it's not working!

Comment: `A::TEXT`, `A::BIN`, just like in one of the links they use `ns::cls::black` instead of `ns::cls::color::black`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It will not work! I don't have an idea of why it's always giving the same error..I've tried several solutions before posting..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`B::FileType` and `A::FileType` are different types.  You need to `typedef A::FileType FileType` inside B to alias the types correctly so they are interchangeable.  Otherwise `B::FileType` is an enum which is *structurally* the same as `A::FileType`, but unrelated in the type system.  This answers your primary question.

Fixing this still won't permit your code to compile, however, and this is not what the error is complaining about.

objectOfClassA is already constructed inside foo_func.  Calling `this->objectOfClassA(filename, type)` is an attempt to use the overloaded () operator on the object; this operator does not exist so the code cannot compile.  You can only construct objectOfClassA via B's constructor using initializer notation, e.g.

```
B::B(const std::string& filename, FileType type) : objectOfClassA(filename, type)
{
  ...
}
```

Then in main you would do this:

```
B objectOfClassB("file_path", B::TEXT);
```

Step through in the debugger to see the control flow.

Comment: so this line `enum FileType{TEXT = A::FileType::TEXT, BIN = A::FileType::BIN};` won't work unless I explicitly typedef `A::FileType`? Thanks for letting me notice what the compiler is complaining about!

Comment: I mean just get rid of that line and use typedef instead

Comment: I've tried by using `typedef` in `Class A` and then just using `A::FileType::TEXT` inside of body of the function of `Class B`, but it still won't work! may the problem be due to the fact that classes are templated? I haven't pointed it out in question cause I thought it was not relevant but maybe it is. (check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940883/does-templatization-affect-enum-type-syntax)

Comment: Eddie can you please tell me why I'm am not able to call constructor of `Class A` even now that I fixed the `enum type` problem?what syntax should I use instead of `this->objectOfClassA(filename, type);`?

Comment: Matteo, I'm not sure how to get notifications of messages on this site yet :)  Sorry I did not see your message.

Short answer: keep the definition of class A exactly as you have it above.  For B, remove enum & foo_func from header, and add a constructor signature `B(const std::string& filename, FileType type)` as you have for A.  For B's cpp file add the constructor I give and remove foo_func.  For main, remove foo_func and initialize B as in the last code snippet in my answer.